# ASP.NET Automated Deployment

Tags: asp.net, build-automation, web-deployment, webdeploy

could any of you, please, tell me or point me to a place where I can find information on how to automate a (what I think is a) simple deployment scenario for ASP.NET applications.

I've an ASP.NET application with multiple publish profiles and web.config transformation files set up.

What I'm looking for is a way to build the project once and then publish it multiple times 
using various specified profiles.

**UPDATE**

So far I've the following `Deploy.cmd` file:

```
msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Profile1;Configuration=%1
msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Profile2;Configuration=%1
```

It works! but it's building the solutions twice, one per publish profile... I tried something like:

```
msbuild /t:Build /p:Configuration=%1
msbuild /t:Publish /p:PublishProfile=Profile1;Configuration=%1
msbuild /t:Publish /p:PublishProfile=Profile2;Configuration=%1
```

It builds but it doesn't publish: `Skipping unpublishable project`

Is there anyway to build the project just once and then publish it using the various profiles?

Comment: Have you checked out MSBuild? It is what Visual Studio uses, but has many more capabilities.

Comment: Have a look at this blog series and note that you can follow his instructions using any source control system that TeamCity supports: http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html

Comment: @JeremyCook I checked out the link, it was great, thanks!